# React JS: remove an item from the localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a workable App where you get from an API some data and that data is randomly changes every 3 seconds and with a button the user can print the data and by pressing again it stops, i have managed to complete this(as seen bellow) part(btw new to react js):

```html
useEffect(() =>{
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getJoke()
    },3000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[])
  //fetch the jokes function
  const getJoke = (() => {
    fetch('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      setKey(res.id);
      setJoke(res.value);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  })
```

i have also made a button where the user can save the data(which randomly appears every 3 sec) on the localStorage of the browser as seen bellow..

```html
const addJokeFav = (() => {
    jokes.push(joke);
    const jokesJsonified = JSON.stringify(jokes);
    localStorage.setItem(key, jokesJsonified);
  })
  
  bellow the render code
  
  <button id="button" onClick={()=>{addJokeFav()}}>Save!</button>
```

but i would like to have only one button where he save one data coming randomly and every 3 seconds, and if he repress the button the data will be deleted from the localStorage. i have this function here which i dont seem to make it work.

```html
const remJokeFav = (() => {
    const jokesJsonified = JSON.stringify(jokes);
    localStorage.removeItem(key, jokesJsonified);
  })
```

it seems that is trying to remove and item that is not there cause of the key, which i take it with setKey(res.id) on the response, on the code above in the first snippet.
my App variables are bellow.

```html
const [joke, setJoke] = useState();
  const [key, setKey] = useState([]);
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
  const jokes = [];
```

Thanks for any help regarding the situation!

Comment: Just to get the question clear, Do you want to remove all jokes from the localStorage or just the current Joke?

Comment: @KarthikRP Just the current joke that just displayed in the screen. the user placed it on the localstorage and if he press again the toggle button or any other button will be deleted

Comment: If you just need to remove the current joke, you need to use removeItem like this `localStorage.removeItem(key)`

Comment: @KarthikRP Seems like the button does not do anything, but if i press it fast enough it delete the entry without appearing on the localstorage. its like it does not let it, and the key changes fast

Comment: Check this, https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-moser-l1xut?file=/src/App.js
You can check the chrome application tab for the data being removed in localStorage.

Comment: @KarthikRP It actually works like that, thanks!!! thought its 5 seconds the time of fetching, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I had set it to 5 sec, you can change it back to three. I'll move my comments as an answer., please do accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be with `localStorage.removeItem(key, jokesJsonified);`
removeItem just needs the key and not the value.

Also there is unnecessary rerender on setting jokes array. Make jokes array as ref instead of state.

Here is an working example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-moser-l1xut?)